# How to retrieve the parameters of a Q# operation?

Tags: programming, q#

How to retrieve the parameters of a Q# operation? Is it possible to do such a thing at all?

Comment: This question seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022076/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-q-operation-parameter - does the answer to that one help you? (I haven't tried doing that kind of thing myself so can't be sure)

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova That answer needs more explanation, what is `IQ#` been mentioned there? Does it help?

Comment: IQ# is the Jupyter kernel for Q#. You can look at the source at https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp. The file src\Core\OperationInfo.cs builds a list of the parameter types using reflection on the Run method of the generated class.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming a 1-1 mapping from a Q# operation with a C# operation but it doesn't work like that. A Q# operation can have a lot more functionality than a C# class, for example, Q# offers the ability to automatically create the `adjoint` and `controlled` versions of a the operation.

As Mariia pointed out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022076/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-q-operation-parameter is a very similar question and the same answer applies:

Each Q# operations generations a C# class that extends the generic class `Operation<I,O>`, so to figure out what the input/output parameters you can take a look at the `BaseType` of the operation's `Type`, and look at the value of the `GenericTypeArguments[0]` to figure out the input type.